# How do I difference time in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, database, time

There's a datetime field "time" and it's in Y-m-d H:i:s format.
All the values are past values.
I need to query that field diffed from current time resulting in seconds.

```
SELECT time FROM table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(),time)) AS time FROM myTable;
```